# Confused between the isomorphism and continuity of $M_n\mathbb{R}$ with $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$

Tags: general-topology, continuity

I've managed to confuse myself while doing a few excercises in topology where I was asked to find the closure of a $M_2(\mathbb{R})$. The following are the questions I have.

1. Is there a continuous map from $f:M_2(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^4$. Why is this map continuous? If so, how do I show in terms of topological spaces. That is if $U$ is an open set then $f^{-1}(U)$ is open.
2. Continuity of topological maps doesn't a prior assume a metric right?
3. I know the $\exists \, f$ such that $f:M_2(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^4$ is an isomorphism. But isomorphism tells nothing about the continuity between topological spaces right?

4.There is a statement as follows :

> Consider $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ with the topology of $\mathbb{C}^{n^2} \cong \mathbb{R}^{2{n^2}}$. Let $D$ be the set of diagonalizable matrices.Find the closure $\bar{D}$ in $M_n(\mathbb{C})$

. I find this to an extremely vague statement. I am not able to understand what topology on $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ they are referring to. Yes, I agree that $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}^{n^2}$ and inturn isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{2{n^2}}$. But! How does that induce a topology on $M_n(\mathbb{C})$?

5. Clearly, the isomorphism is inducing a topology which I dont see how. I've all these questioned jumbled up, unable to sort them systematically. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Assuming that we know the topology om $\mathbb{R}^{2{n^2}}$ (AGAIN! what exactly is the topology on $\mathbb{R}^{2{n^2}}$ that we are assuming, is the box topology with standard basis?

Comment: Usually, they mean the "standard" topology, which is generated by the Euclidean metric on $\Bbb R^{2n^2}$, and is also the box topology and the product topology (these only differ for product spaces with infinite number of factors). You can then use the inner product norm to define a norm on $M_n(\Bbb C)$. Even more basically, you can use the isomorphism $f$ to define open sets in $M_n(\Bbb C)$ as pre-images under $f$ of open sets in the standard topology in $\Bbb R^{2n^2}$, which automatically makes $f$ continuous.

Comment: Brilliant! That clears all my doubts in a nice simple paragraph! :)